# PostgreSQL lower case or remove double quotes on every table name before select query

Tags: postgresql, trigger, functions, case-sensitive

We are migrating from OracleDB to PostgreSQL and all the tables name in database are lower case while the script from application is mixed with double quotes.

For example the code in application like this:

```
SELECT * FROM "USER_ID";
```

Can it be change to:

```
SELECT * FROM "user_id";
or
SELECT * FROM USER_ID;
```

Is there anyway to lower case or remove double quotes for every tables name on query?

Comment: Sorry, bad example. I've edited my question, is there anyway when the code executed by application with double quotes, DB engine then remove the double quotes and run the query.

Comment: Well, just remove all double quotes: when _creating_ the tables and when referencing them.

Comment: The tables are all in lowercase already, but the application code is mixed. The task is to make it work without touching the application

Comment: You can't. You need to remove the double quotes inside the application code

Comment: The alternative is to rename the tables and columns to upper case (with double quotes).